# Typescript: How to declare a dependant property?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a declaration file for the quadstore library. The library defines a class that takes a constructor parameter `contextKey`. The value of this parameter determines the name of a field on method arguments. Simplifying, the equivalent Typescript would be:

```
interface MethodArg {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  <<Whatever is supplied as the value of contextKey or a default name>>: string;
}

class A {
  constructor(options?: {contextKey: string}) {}

  fn(arg: MethodArg) {...}
}
```

How do I declare the type of `MethodArg` to say that the third property name depends on the value given to the class constructor (in a declaration file)? Is this possible at all?

Comment: Generics, probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this is possible as i understand the *value* of the constructor parameter is defined at runtime, but the type of MethodArg is defined at compile time(?), so the latter one can not depend on the former one, but if you prefer to elevate the value to a type parameter(thus to provide runtime information to compile time), maybe you could do it like this

```js
type MethodArg<E extends keyof any> = {
  [T in E]: string;
} & { a: string; b: string };

class A<T extends string> {
  constructor(options?: { contextKey: T }) {}
  fn(arg: MethodArg<T>) {}
}

new A({ contextKey: "foo" }).fn({
  a: "100",
  b: "100",
  foo: "foo",
});


// not the following way
let foo: string = "123";
new A({ contextKey: foo }).fn({
  a: "100",
  b: "200",
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a very interesting! I agree it's a difficult thing to express in a type decleration. This is ingenious and probably as close as we can get